# How do i flush the state store in a kafka streams application?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to flush the state store from a Kafka streams application ie I don't want to use the topology but rather just execute something like a `store.flush()` to flush out all the records in the store

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to use the topology" ?